# Are starting cards in Principato unbalanced?

Tags: principato

In Principato each player randomly gets one card that allows them to build a facility: a house, a bank, a field or a farm. However, only houses and fields yield resources needed to expand your principality, forcing players that drew banks or farms to exchange them quickly. Additionally, it makes these players late starters in a run for farms and houses, which often happens in 4-player setup.

Is there something I'm missing here, or are the starting cards unbalanced?

*Note:* I know that you can draw a more or less fitting set of starting action and goal cards, but I'm asking only about the 4 starting action cards that allow you to build something.